# Modelamiento base de datos relacional

Tags: sql, modelorelacional

Estoy tratando de consultar cuantos empleados asistieron en una fecha "xxxx-xx-xx" a una instalación, pero tengo el problema de que si el empleado realizo asistencias en una instalación y después este se cambia de instalación al contar las asistencias de una instalación me contara las asistencias que el empleado realizo en otra instalación también.

Esta es mi consulta SQL, pero tambien me devuelve las asitencias que un empleado realizo en otras instalaciones:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cantidad_de_asistentes
FROM Asistencia AS A
INNER JOIN Instalacion_Empleado AS IE ON A.rut_empleado_fk = IE.rut_empleado_fk
WHERE IE.id_instalacion_fk = 2
AND A.fecha_asistencia = '2023-10-14'
```

[image: Ejemplo Modelo base de datos]

Comment: Yo creo que lo más fácil sería guardar la clave de la instalación en la tabla Asistencia. Por otro lado, en Instalacion_Empleado, quizás una fechaFin sería interesante.

Comment: Sí que tienes una ambigüedad en el modelado. Cuando un empleado asiste, ¿a qué instalación está asistiendo? ¿A la que tenga asignada en Instalacion_Empleado? ¿Y cómo haces cuando cambia de instalación? ¿Está en la última hasta que tienes una nueva fecha_ingreso_instalacion?

Comment: Quizás podría ser un atributo estado en instalación empleado y preguntar si está activo o no si está activo pertenece a la instalación

Comment: En base a que asistencia tenga como foren key la ID de la instalación, ¿No me quedaría una relación circular?

Answer (score 0):

Estás empezando la casa por el tejado, no puedes pensar en las FK si antes no tienes claro el modelo ER o conceptual de lo que quieres modelar. Las preguntas que te he hecho han sido para ayudarte a diseñarlo, pero estás más preocupado por la implementación física que por los datos que quieres almacenar y esto funciona justo al revés.

Para el caso concreto de lo que buscas, te basta con un simple DISTINCT:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT rut_empleado_fk) AS cantidad_de_asistentes
  FROM Asistencia AS A
  INNER JOIN Instalacion_Empleado AS IE
  ON A.rut_empleado_fk = IE.rut_empleado_fk
  WHERE IE.id_instalacion_fk = 2 AND A.fecha = '2023-10-14';
```

Esto te funcionará, pero el diseño es un poco extraño y no se entiende muy bien qué se intenta modelar, ni por qué se está modelando así: horas extras por un lado, asistencia por otra, instalaciones en las que se ingresa por otra... Parece todo un poco improvisado, cuando seguro que todo está relacionado entre sí y se podría llegar a un esquema bastante más claro.

De momento deja esta pregunta así, pero te animo a formular otra en la que describas cómo funciona la gestión de empleados, qué datos recopilas y qué necesitas obtener a partir de éstos: cómo es la asignación a instalaciones, cómo se calculan las horas extras, etc.